# Detecting PDF is corrupt or password protected by Blue Prism

Tags: pdf, blueprism

Is there any VBO or method in Blue Prism to detect if a PDF is corrupt (meaning can't be opened) or password protected. So that can be stored as a boolean value in a decision variable?

Comment: *"PDF is corrupt (meaning can't be opened)"* - can't be opened by what software? Different PDF processors have different levels of leniency towards corruptions. In particular PDF viewers are notorious for repairing numerous PDF errors under the hood.

Comment: This is for Adobe Acrobat DC. If Adobe Acrobat DC can't open such files.

Comment: I doubt any software but Adobe Acrobat itself (or the underlying libraries) will be able to truly check this.

Comment: Is there any dll do you know for which I can write custom code in Blue Prism for detecting MIME types if the document is actually pdf or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by using the [SRI Infotech PDF Utility asset](https://digitalexchange.blueprism.com/dx/entry/14958/solution/sri---utility---pdf) from Blue Prism DX portal. It has a itextsharp.dll and a VBO for PDF functionalities. Custom coding in C# was required to solve the problem statement. The custom C# code used was

```
pdfErrorMessage="";
validPdf=false;
try{
PdfReader r = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
if (r.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions)
{
   validPdf=true;
}
}
catch(Exception e) {
 pdfErrorMessage = e.ToString();
 validPdf=false;
}
```

Comment: This checks whether iTextSharp can open the file in question, not Adobe Acrobat DC as you said in a comment. Often that will be the same but there are occasional differences.

Comment: Yes, true. Almost all of the cases I saw till now itextsharp and adobe are behaving the same in opening such files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to an ASPOSE licence you can use the .net command **fileInfo.HasOpenPassword** on a vbo with Aspose.Pdf.dll enabled.

Using this method you will have to load the file with something like `New PDFFileInfo(yourPDFDocument)`  which will throw a specific error if the file is corrupt.